# Error: EMFILE: too many open files

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, npm

Using nw.js, I am just trying to save images in an array of img elements with different random names.

But having a few errors, is something wrong with my code?

```
for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
 request(imgs[i].getAttribute('src')).on('error', function(err) {
  throw err
 }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('data/imgs/' + randomString))
}
```

imgs[] is an array of 100-500 html  img element, but I am receiving

```
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open *<directory>*
```

And another error:

```
"Uncaught Error: socket hang up"
```

Although it saves some images, some of them are corrupted, and it creates too many images than there actually is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`graceful-fs`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs) module, which is a drop-in replacement for the `fs` module. It is a wrapper around the native `fs` module. Quoting the [docs of `graceful-fs` module](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs#improvements-over-fs-module),

> Queues up `open` and `readdir` calls, and retries them once something closes if there is an `EMFILE` error from too many file descriptors.

Since it exposes the same APIs as the native `fs` module, you can use it just like the normal `fs` module.

```
// use just like fs
var fs = require('graceful-fs');
```

**Note:** This library was created by, Isaac Z. Schlueter, one of the core developers of the Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution would be just to wait for file to be downloaded and only then open new request by using recursion:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

var dest = '../data/downloads/';

function _saveAllFiles (fileUrlArray, curIdx, options) {
    try {
        var count = fileUrlArray.length - 1;
        var curFile = fileUrlArray[curIdx];

        var stream = request(curFile)
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest + "file_" + curIdx));

        stream.on('finish', function () {
            console.log("Downloaded", curFile);
            stream.close();
            if (curIdx + 1 < count) {
                //Finished, download next file
                _saveAllFiles(fileArray, curIdx + 1, options);
            }
        });
        stream.on('error', function () {
            console.log("Error", curFile);
            stream.close();
            stream.end();
            if (curIdx + 1 < count) {
                //Error occured, go to next file
                _saveAllFiles(fileArray, curIdx + 1, options);
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Failed to download file", err);
    }
}
```